# VueJS (or Vanilla JS) Test object for filtered results that includes secondary search

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, include

I have been working on an interesting situation that I have been unable to determine why it isn't working as expected. The code that I have here is the latest attempt, and I believe it is close, just missing something. If anyone could help me out that would be great. (This is a volunteer project I am doing for an animal adoption agency)

Here is the setup:

I have a firebase database that has approx. 7,000 adopters. They are broken into a Object like so:

```
{
  ApplicantCellPhone: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  ApplicantCity: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  ApplicantDLNum: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  ApplicantEmail: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  ApplicantEmployerName: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  ApplicantFirstName: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  ApplicantHomePhone: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  ApplicantLastName: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  ApplicantStreet: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  ApplicantZip: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  CoapplicantCellPhone: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  CoapplicantCity: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  CoapplicantDLNum: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  CoapplicantEmail: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  CoapplicantEmployerName: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  CoapplicantFirstName: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  CoapplicantHomePhone: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  CoapplicantLastName: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  CoapplicantStreet: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
  CoapplicantZip: "ADOPTERS ACTUAL INFORMATION",
}
```

Now I have a search box like this:

```
<b-form-input id="searchInputString" v-model="searchInputString" name="searchInputString" type="text" placeholder="Search Adopters" class="form-control mb-3" autocomplete="off" @keyup.native="filterAdopters" />
```

With the @keyup is going to this function:

```
filterAdopters: function(event) {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.adoptersFilteredDataCollection = {}
    this.spiltFilteredData = []

    if (!this.isNullOrEmpty(this.searchInputString)) {
      let searchArray = this.searchInputString.split(" ")
      console.log('Search Array =>', searchArray)

      for (let i = 0; i <= searchArray.length; i++) {
        this.spiltFilteredData.push(this.allAdoptersData.filter(s =>
          s.ApplicantCellPhone.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.ApplicantCity.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.ApplicantDLNum.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.ApplicantEmail.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.ApplicantEmployerName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.ApplicantFirstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.ApplicantHomePhone.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.ApplicantLastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.ApplicantStreet.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.ApplicantZip.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.CoapplicantCellPhone.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.CoapplicantCity.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.CoapplicantDLNum.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.CoapplicantEmail.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.CoapplicantEmployerName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.CoapplicantFirstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.CoapplicantHomePhone.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.CoapplicantLastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.CoapplicantStreet.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
          s.CoapplicantZip.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchInputString.toLowerCase()) > -1
        ))
      }
    }
    else {
      this.searchInputString = ''
      this.spiltFilteredData = {}
    }

    console.log('spiltFilteredData', this.spiltFilteredData)
  })
},
```

I don't want to assume anything, so I just want to explain what I am doing...

By removing the let searchArray = this.searchInputString.split(" ") If I type in Kimberly it will return 345 results, now I want to filter down by the space to start the search over again, from the 345 results. So if I type in Kimberly Brown it should return 13 results, now by pressing  again, from the 13 results, I start typing in Hillsboro (That is the city), it will return 2 results, then I  and type in 345 Center St it will then return 1 result with the correct Kimberly. I though I would convert them to an array then use includes, although this isn't boding as well as I thought... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign all rows into variable `results`, and then in `for` keep filtering results with

```
results = results.filter(s => {....
```

For each word in your search input, it will keep narrowing down matching rows.

I didn't test this out, but it should work

```
filterAdopters: function(event) {
  this.spiltFilteredData = []

  if (!this.isNullOrEmpty(this.searchInputString)) {
    let searchArray = this.searchInputString.split(" ")
    console.log('Search Array =>', searchArray)

    // get all rows
    let results = this.allAdoptersData.map(s => {
      // concatenate all props and lowercase them to avoid doing it multiple times in `for` loop
      // add new helper property `concatenatedProps` to all rows - we will remove it after
      s.concatenatedProps  = [
        s.ApplicantCellPhone,
        s.ApplicantCity,
        s.ApplicantDLNum,
        s.ApplicantEmail,
        s.ApplicantEmployerName,
        s.ApplicantFirstName,
        s.ApplicantHomePhone,
        s.ApplicantLastName,
        s.ApplicantStreet,
        s.ApplicantZip,
        s.CoapplicantCellPhone,
        s.CoapplicantCity,
        s.CoapplicantDLNum,
        s.CoapplicantEmail,
        s.CoapplicantEmployerName,
        s.CoapplicantFirstName,
        s.CoapplicantHomePhone,
        s.CoapplicantLastName,
        s.CoapplicantStreet,
        s.CoapplicantZip
      ].join(' ') // because we don't search ' ', we can use it to join text
       .toLowerCase()

      return s
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
      let searchText = searchArray[i].toLowerCase();

      results = results.filter( s => s.concatenatedProps.indexOf( searchText) !== -1 )
    }

    this.spiltFilteredData = results.map(s => {
      // remove helper property
      delete s.concatenatedProps

      return s
    })

  } else {
    this.searchInputString = ''
    this.spiltFilteredData = []
  }

  console.log('spiltFilteredData', this.spiltFilteredData)
},
```

Comment: Amazing, I was missing mapping all of the item and joining them by space then filtering from there. This actually worked amazingly and I am very thankful.

Comment: Joining by space was not needed, it was just to avoid all those `toLowerCase` in each `for` iteration. And I just find it easier to read :) You were just missing assigning filtered results back to same variable, and filtering it back again. Also, you were iterating `searchArray`, but comparing values with `this.searchInputString` (full search text, not search words). You were almost there! I'm glad i could help